# How to aggregate the data with 5-min-interval for each group?

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

Here is my data.

```
a <-
structure(list(timestamp1.x = c("2019-05-31 18:27:34", "2019-05-31
18:28:34",  "2019-05-31 18:29:34", "2019-05-31 18:29:59", "2019-05-31
18:35:35",  "2019-05-31 18:35:43", "2019-05-31 18:41:43", "2019-05-31
18:42:45",  "2019-05-31 18:49:34", "2019-05-31 18:50:34"), sensor =
c("A",  "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A"), direction =
c(-75, 
-78, -58, -54, -72, -47, -57, -51, -75, -78)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to aggregate the data with 5-min-interval for each sensors.
This is the trial.

```
aa <- a %>%
  mutate(timestamp1.x = as.POSIXct(timestamp1.x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(sensor, timestamp1.x = cut(timestamp1.x, breaks="5 min")) %>%
  summarize(mean_direction = mean(direction))
```

And this is the result table.

```
  sensor timestamp1.x        mean_direction
  <chr>  <fct>                        <dbl>
1 A      2019-05-31 18:27:00          -66.2
2 A      2019-05-31 18:47:00          -76.5
3 B      2019-05-31 18:32:00          -59.5
4 C      2019-05-31 18:37:00          -57  
5 C      2019-05-31 18:42:00          -51
```

However, I would like to aggregate it for each group (sensor).

It means, in case of sensor A, the data should be aggregated in 18:27:00 to 18:31:59 (5-min-interval). For sensor B, the data from 18:35:00 to 18:39:49 (5-min-interval) should be aggregated.

This is a result I want.

```
  sensor timestamp1.x        mean_direction
  <chr>  <fct>                        <dbl>
1 A      2019-05-31 18:27:00          -66.2
2 A      2019-05-31 18:49:00          -76.5
3 B      2019-05-31 18:35:00          -59.5
4 C      2019-05-31 18:41:00          -54
```

How do I add some functions and options in the 'group_by' or other codes?

Comment: With the sample code you provided it seems like it is sufficient to only `group_by` on `sensor`, since a different `sensor` seems to be associated with a different `5 minute interval` anyway. Does the following work? 

`df %>% 
  group_by(sensor) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(direction))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However in the full dataset, there are more observations for each sensors. This is an example. (sensor: A, time stamp: 19:00:00). That's why I should aggregate the data with time interval and each sensor.

Comment: Could you update your question with a sample dataset that contains such data? (preferably with `dput()`)

Comment: I have just updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what the question asks for.
The trick is to group by `sensor` only, then `cut` the `timestamp1.x`, then group by both `sensor` and `timestamp1.x`.

```
bb <- b %>%
  mutate(timestamp1.x = as.POSIXct(timestamp1.x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(sensor) %>%
  mutate(timestamp1.x = as.character(cut(timestamp1.x, breaks="5 min"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(sensor, timestamp1.x) %>%
  summarize(mean_direction = mean(direction))
```

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100
timestamp1.x <- as.POSIXct("2019-05-31 00:00:00") + cumsum(sample(60, n, TRUE))
sensor <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, TRUE)
direction <- sample(0:-100, n, TRUE)
b <- data.frame(timestamp1.x, sensor, direction)
b <- b[with(b, order(sensor, timestamp1.x)), ]
row.names(b) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sequentially add the groupings. So, first `group_by(sensor)` and then `group_by(timestamp1.x = cut(...), add = T)`.

```
a%>%
  mutate(timestamp1.x = as.POSIXct(timestamp1.x))%>%
  group_by(sensor)%>%
  group_by(timestamp1.x = as.character(cut(timestamp1.x, breaks="5 min")),add = T)%>%
  summarize(mean_direction = mean(direction))
```

**Edit:** Added `as.character` in group_by call. Before, it would drop the `sensor` field during the `summarize`. It works as intended now.